# UIScrollview size when orientation changes

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

it seems when I change the orientation of my phone when I am looking at an image in a scroll view, the scrollview dose not change orientation with the phone.

Im wondering if someone can explain to me how to accomplish this.

these are the setting in my interface builder

[image]

I have just been doing some research and now have the first selection working, but if i try another picture it dosnt work.. and I'm not sure why.. heres my code

this is what has made it semi work

```
scrollView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight); 


- (void)loadImage:(NSString *)myImageName
{
//    //Create scrollview

    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
    scrollView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight); 
    scrollView.delegate = self;

    //Create scrollviewimage
    if ([myImageName isEqualToString:@"one"]) {
        image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"hyundai.png"]];
        containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 350, 550)];
        NSLog(@"1");
    }
    if ([myImageName isEqualToString:@"two"]) {
        image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"keso.png"]];
        containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 520)];
        NSLog(@"2");
    }
    if ([myImageName isEqualToString:@"three"]) {
        image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"conforti.png"]];
        containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 700)];
        NSLog(@"3");
    }

    //Add subview
    [containerView addSubview:image];
    //initViews
//    scrollView.contentSize = containerView.frame.size;
    [scrollView addSubview:containerView];

    //scrolling
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 31.0;
    scrollView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor;
    [scrollView setZoomScale:scrollView.minimumZoomScale];

    //highrachy
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
    scrollView = nil;
}
```

EDIT: response to @DJ

this is the output

```
2012-02-01 13:30:35.683 Diagram Test[1672:707] The view controller <UINavigationController: 0x14cdd0> returned NO from -shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: for all interface orientations. It should support at least one orientation.
2012-02-01 13:30:44.182 Diagram Test[1672:707] height = (null)i, width = (null)i
2012-02-01 13:30:47.097 Diagram Test[1672:707] height = (null)i, width = (null)i
2012-02-01 13:30:47.158 Diagram Test[1672:707] height = (null)i, width = (null)i
2012-02-01 13:30:51.509 Diagram Test[1672:707] height = (null)i, width = (null)i
2012-02-01 13:30:51.555 Diagram Test[1672:707] height = (null)i, width = (null)i
2012-02-01 13:30:55.473 Diagram Test[1672:707] height = (null)i, width = (null)i
2012-02-01 13:30:55.519 Diagram Test[1672:707] height = (null)i, width = (null)i
2012-02-01 13:30:59.293 Diagram Test[1672:707] height = (null)i, width = (null)i
2012-02-01 13:30:59.352 Diagram Test[1672:707] height = (null)i, width = (null)i
2012-02-01 13:31:02.237 Diagram Test[1672:707] height = (null)i, width = (null)i
2012-02-01 13:31:02.281 Diagram Test[1672:707] height = (null)i, width = (null)i
2012-02-01 13:31:03.814 Diagram Test[1672:707] height = (null)i, width = (null)i
2012-02-01 13:31:03.858 Diagram Test[1672:707] height = (null)i, width = (null)i
```

Comment: what's your code for adding the image to the UIScrollView?  Do other objects change orientation?  actually after what you've posted it like you have a UIScrollView taking up the entire Iphone screen, it's probably your view controller.

Answer (score 2):

Rotating a scrollview will resize the bounds, but not the contentSize, which isn't affected by autoresize.

The contentSize is the scrollable area of a scrollview, so you will need to resize it manually during rotation.  This can lead to a slew of other adjustments, so be warned that rotating a scrollview can be a bit tricky.

For example, if you are scrolling through a list of images, you will also need to realign the scroll position and possibly modify the zoom setting to match new width and height.

If you are just zooming on a single image the task is a bit easier as only zoom needs to be adjust, if at all.

Another hint:  Play with contentSize without rotating so you can see how it affects the scrolling and visible area.

Answer (score 0):

Those are the correct springs and struts to have the scroll view fill the parent view on orientation change.  The problem is most likely the scrollview content not adapting.

Also take a look modifying scrollview.contentSize and scrollView.contentOffest in willRotateToInterfaceOrientation: method if you need to keep the image centered etc.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the content is fine, check out my question again as I have updated it with something I have just found that worked on one of the pictures.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling nothing is rotating..

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
     NSLog(@"height = %i, width = %i",scrollviewname.bounds.size.height, scrollviewname.bounds.size.width);
     return true;
}
```

I typed that code from memory.. so if there's a spelling mistake sorry.. check those logs to make sure uiscrollview is rotating first.

Comment: i posted response to this in my question